# Erlang - Removing repeating tuples according to first value

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I am trying to create a function that will look into a list of tuples and remove the ones that have identical first elements. For example:

```
rmvSameTpl([{2,1}, {2,1}, {3,1}, {2,1}]).
```

should return [{2,1}, {3,1}].

The problem is my function always returns only the first tuple and as I'm a beginner I can't figure out why that is the case?

```
-export([rmvSameTpl/1]).

rmvSameTpl ([])-> [];
rmvSameTpl ([Z])-> [Z];
rmvSameTpl ( [H|T] ) -> 
    [H| [L || L<-rmvSameTpl(T), (element(1, H)) /= (element(1, T))] ].
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a wrong comparison in the last case: `(element(1, H)) /= (element(1, T))` instead of `(element(1, H)) /= (element(1, L))`. It fails with an exception, since `T` is a list and not a tuple. But in Erlang list comprehensions, failing filters are treated as `false`, so `[L || L<-rmvSameTpl(T), (element(1, H)) /= (element(1, T))]` ends up being the empty list.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach has O(N^2) time complexity. There is obvious simple O(N*logN) solution:

```
1> lists:ukeysort(1, [{2,1}, {2,1}, {3,1}, {2,1}]).
[{2,1},{3,1}]
```

Comment: That's actually a great tip, actually I forgot to mention that we should do this with the basic knowledge i.e. no libraries, but the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you just made a typo, you use element(1,T) instead of element (1,L). using

```
[H| [L || L<-rmvSameTpl(T), (element(1, H)) /= (element(1, L))] ].
```

your code works, but I am not comfortable with performance and stack size if you ever use big lists.

Comment: And that's why you don't code in the middle of the night. Thanks a ton.